# SAP B1 Studio Addon installation and Registration

Tags: visual-studio, add-on, sapb1

I have created SAP add-on Project in B1 Studio. I was trying to create the installation file for this. But I am facing many difficulties while doing it as I have not done this before and I am unable to find proper documentation for so.

I followed following steps to create one.

1. Created add-on using add-on installer.
2. In add on registration wizard I gave address of the newly created .exe file.
3. I created one more folder and pasted all these file in that along with my project's .exe file and interlop dll.
4. In sap I registered the add-on and tried to install it.
   But it is giving me no executable file found error.

Comment: are you using SAP 9.0 or above?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using SAP 9.0 or above, you can create an extension package. Go to the SAP installation directory and find the ExtensionPackage.exe

Path can be something like this
C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\SAP Business One SDK\Tools\ExtensionPackage

- Run this application and enter all mandatory fileds in Basic
  information
- select the 32 bit version / 64 bit version of your application
- select additional files if needed.
- mark to register 32/64 bit dlls if needed
- click package button to save it.

Now you can go to your SAP Business one and open Administration > Add-ons > Add-On administration

- click the *Manage Extensions for Lightweight Deployment* [this should open the control center in a web browser]
- login using your B1site user ID n pass which will take you to extension manager.
- Use import to import the package you created
- Use Comany Assignment to assign to the correct SAP comapany.
- Login to the SAP company to install the extension.